# Console Error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined - openModal()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Link to this project on GitHub: 
https://github.com/sheedSVNTH/MERN-expense-manager-app

Im getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

I've binded, "this" correctly.  Here is a snippet of my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
var querystring = require('querystring');

class Add extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            description: '',
            amount: '',
            month: '',
            year: '',
            messageFromServer: '',
            modalIsOpen: false
        }

    this.handleSelectChange = this.handleSelectChange.bind(this);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
    this.insertNewExpense = this.insertNewExpense.bind(this);
    this.openModel = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
}
openModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
}
closeModal() {
    this.setState({
        modalIsOpen: false,
        description: '',
        amount: '',
        month: 'Jan',
        year: 2018,
        messageFromServer: ''
    });
}
```

Comment: `this.openModel = this.openModal.bind(this);` ... can you see the typo? openMod*e*l !== openMod*a*l - so therefore you haven't *binded, "this" correctly* for `openModal`

Comment: @jaromandaX I suppose that would matter, right, haha.  thank-you for looking at this.  I must have needed the fresh eyes. This item is working now, need to fix the next uncovered bug.